# The last child of a button group is not recognized by Bootstrap. How do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

It's a small but pesky issue. The last button of my button group is rectangular – as opposed to being rounded at top right and bottom right corners. The reason is this: besides the `a.btn` element, the `btn-group` has a modal which, in Bootstrap's opinion, *is* the group's last child. The modal is called by that last button so for convenience, I want it to stay there instead of moving it around and lose it at some point (or have trouble finding)

**What do you think I should do to ensure proper style of my button group's last button?** I mean surely I can manually add this attribute, `style="border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem; border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem`, and thereby override Bootstrap's CSS on that one, but it's ugly. Maybe, I can manually assign last children? Simply typing "lastchild" inside the opening tag, for example, would be a relatively nice solution (it's a pitty I can't do that)

[image]

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Admin Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                                <th scope="col">Buttons</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you not move the modal in front of the last button, so that it is still close to it, but not the last element in the parent?

Comment: You should not have one "delete modal" per table row, but one "delete modal" overall. When the delete button is clicked, pass in the ID/email/whatever of the user. Doing it this way also happens to fix your problem. Bootstrap has an example for this type of thing: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content. Or Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: @Geshode it would compromise readability (which is already low af as Bootstrap makes for pretty ugly code as it is, imho)

Comment: How would it compromise readability, if you move it one line up?

Comment: @Geshode it is more clear to me when I see a button and then what happens when you press it, not the other way around

Comment: @Sergey You can place the modal in another wrapper if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overruling Bootstrap's CSS and making use of the `:last-of-type` pseudo class is, in my view, the perfect solution. Adding `!important` is, well, important because more specific selectors (in particular, `.btn-group>.btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle)`) may ruin your plan

```css
.btn-group a:last-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
.btn-group a:last-of-type {
border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
}
        </style>
        <title>Admin Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                                <th scope="col">Buttons</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-right" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-right" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [border-radius](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/borders/#border-radius) utilities of bootstrap for that. Just add `rounded-right` bootstrap class in last button instead of inline css.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Admin Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                                <th scope="col">Buttons</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-right" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-right" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you! But `.btn-group-sm .btn` has a border radius of 0.2rem while `rounded-right` sets it at 0.25rem. So it's not perfect (though, I concede that most people wouldn't notice the difference)

Comment: Do you think I can overrule Bootstrap CSS on that one with some pseudo :last-anchor-child class (I hope, you get the general idea)?

Comment: I discovered that `.btn-group a:last-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem !important;
}` is so much better. I think it's a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `a.btn.btn-outline-primary` class for the solution.

```css
a.btn.btn-outline-primary {
border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Admin Page</title>

<style>
a.btn.btn-outline-primary {
border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px !important;
}

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                                <th scope="col">Buttons</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                                <td class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#">1st button</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">2nd button</a>
                                    <p hidden>Anything at all</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```